# gcc error on a code can be properly compiled by cc and g77

Tags: gcc, makefile, cc, g77

There is an example C code linking to two static libraries. 
This code is compiled via a Makefile. The makefile generates first of all an object file from source file, and then covert it to an executable file via the following commands. In addition, links two libraries to the compiled code:

```
cc -I.  -DUNIX -c cademo1.c
g77  -o cademo1 cademo1.o ../libChemAppC.a ../libLChemApp.a
```

These two commands are the output of the Makefile. If I can run them by my own, they work.

Now, I need to compile the code by gcc:

```
$ gcc -static cademo1.c -L.. -lChemAppC -lLChemApp -o cademo1
```

But it makes hundreds of such errors:

```
.
.
.
rtrnshdr.f:(.text+0x1551): undefined reference to `s_rsue'
rtrnshdr.f:(.text+0x1564): undefined reference to `do_uio'
rtrnshdr.f:(.text+0x156c): undefined reference to `e_rsue'
../libLChemApp.a(bindummy.o): In function `tqhbix_':
bindummy.f:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `s_copy'
../libLChemApp.a(dt.o): In function `tqdtforid_':
dt.f:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `s_copy'
../libLChemApp.a(dt.o): In function `tqhdt_':
dt.f:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `G77_date_and_time_0'
dt.f:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `s_wsfi'
dt.f:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `do_fio'
dt.f:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `do_fio'
dt.f:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `do_fio'
dt.f:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `do_fio'
dt.f:(.text+0xed): undefined reference to `do_fio'
../libLChemApp.a(dt.o):dt.f:(.text+0x101): more undefined references to `do_fio' follow
../libLChemApp.a(dt.o): In function `tqhdt_':
dt.f:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to `e_wsfi'
../libLChemApp.a(dt.o): In function `tqhdat_':
dt.f:(.text+0x1f4): undefined reference to `G77_date_and_time_0'
../libLChemApp.a(dt.o): In function `tqhgmy_':
dt.f:(.text+0x22d): undefined reference to `G77_date_and_time_0'
../libLChemApp.a(progcali.o): In function `tqhpnid_':
progcali.f:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `s_copy'
progcali.f:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `s_copy'
progcali.f:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `s_copy'
progcali.f:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `s_copy'
progcali.f:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `s_copy'
../libLChemApp.a(progcali.o):progcali.f:(.text+0xf7): more undefined references to `s_copy' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could anyone tell me how can I compile a program by gcc which can be properly compiled by cc and g77?

Is there any compiler args which can be added to gcc to functions the same as g77?

Comment: `g77` is a fortran compiler... why would `gcc` be able to do the same thing? You should be able to replace `cc` with `gcc` in those original commands though. I suppose you might be able to tell `gcc` to operate in fortran mode with a flag too... that might work.

Answer (score 0):

As Etan mentions, `g77` is a FORTRAN compiler.  You are using it as a linker here (linking objects and libraries together into a program).  This, plus your error messages, make pretty clear that at least one of those libraries you're linking are written in FORTRAN.

The easiest solution is to continue to use `g77` to link.  The linker will add special compiler-specific libraries to the program for you; for example if you link with `g++` (the C++ compiler/linker) then it will add in the standard STL library, etc.

You don't say why using `g77` is not acceptable, but if it's not you'll have to figure out what extra libraries `g77` is linking and add them to your `gcc` link line by hand.

I don't have it installed so I can't tell you what they are, but you can run `g77 -v ...` and it should show you the command the `g77` front-end uses to invoke the linker: the extra libraries you need should show up there.

Comment: missed -DUNIX as well

Comment: True, but that's a compile-time flag: it's not likely to help with linker errors in the already-built libraries.  It's possible (if the UNIX define would cause those objects in the libraries to not be linked at all), but not likely.

Comment: `but that's a compile-time flag: it's not likely to help with linker errors in the already-built libraries`. But it might be influencing the fortran names mangling. For example, on some platforms fortran routines are those with prefix or postfix underscore (`tqhpnid_` loosk like one), and some define in C might be about selecting right declaration/name for fortran routine.